# How to find union of list of list in sage?

Tags: sage

For example, `l1=[[1,2],[3,4]]` and `l2=[[4,5],[1,2]]` then I need `l3` is union of `l1` and `l2` that is `l3=[[1,2],[3,4],[4,5]]`. order is not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably faster ways to do this, but this works:

```
sage: l1 = [[1,2], [3,4]]
sage: l2 = [[4,5], [1,2]]
sage: l3 = copy(l1)
sage: [l3.append(a) for a in l2 if a not in l1]
[None]
sage: l3
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```